# opening a website error

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, url

I'm trying to have the phrase session one open up a website when clicked. Here is the code that I have

```
<p class="text-info"><a href="WebsiteName">Session One</a></p>
```

The url path is correct when I click it I get this error

```
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

Comment: Is it an external site or internal page? Either way, your url is probably not correct. Can you access url directly in a browser? It would help to share the actual url.

Comment: If the URL is an internal page, try using [Url.Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.routing.urlhelper?view=aspnetcore-2.1) to access the link.

Comment: You definitely need to provide more info. Obviously `WebsiteName` is not a URL. So what is this? A property on your view model? A variable in your .cshtml? The name of an action method? Maybe you're using webforms and it's a property in your code behind? This will be easy to fix if you provide the right information.

Answer (score 0):

Change 'WebsiteName' for the URL you want to go to.

```
<p class="text-info"><a href="http://gogle.com">Session One</a></p>
```